# How to get database value in json format

Tags: json

I have the following code which gives `static data in json` :

```
var Movies0 = 
[ 
 { 
  name: 'Once Upon a Time in the West',
  rating: '8.7',
  director: 'Sergio Leone',
  year: '1968',
  actor: 'Henry Fonda' 
 },

 { 
  name: 'Terminator 2: Judgment Day',
  rating: '8.6',
  director: 'James Cameron',
  year: '1991',
  actor: 'Arnold Schwarzenegger' 
 }
];
  var Movies = [Movies0];
```

i want this code to output data from my database rather then putting static value

Comment: What database? What programming language?

Comment: i want the above structure to be generated dynamically from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP (which I'm assuming you're using), you only have to connect to your database, query something and then encode it as JSON. It's actually really easy!

```
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
$sql='SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 WHERE condition';

$rs=$conn->query($sql);

$data = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```

That simple code example should help you understand the process. Don't forget the error handling when implementing it though, I left it out to simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to do are:
1.Create a model classes of your database
2.Use some json library ( Json.net, Gson ) depending on the platform.
3.If you are working with Json.net ( in Microsoft platforms) you could do:

```
string serialzedobject = JsonConvert.SerialzeObject(your_database_object)
```

similarly for deserializing.

4.If you use Java than Gson is probably the best option, so you will do:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
string serializedobject = toJson(your_database_object)
```

to get it back:

```
Database_type database = fromJson( serializedobject, Database_type.class);
```

I hope this gives you an idea.